# How to launch a test on a Firefox browser with Jenkins in a virtual machine?

Tags: firefox, jenkins, browser, virtual-machine

I am finding a way to launch several tests with Jenkins on a Firefox browser.

I went to "Configure" in the section "This build is parametized" in order to add "firefox" as a name with a "String parameter". But it did not work.

Comment: can you share you pipeline so we can help?

Comment: I have found a way to do it by changing the name of the browser in the browser.ini file then sending it into the master branch of my repository.